# JQuery: How to Use IF statement correctly with ">,<,="

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).on("click", "#cals", function () {
     var year = $('#age').val();
     var name = $('#namee').val();
     var agese = 2018 - year;
     var results = name + " Your age is " +agese;
     if($(year).val() < '2018'){
         $('#ageres').val(results)    
     }
});
```

The `if` statement is not working even if the user entered a number less than 2018.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a value as a jQuery selector:

```
    var year = $('#age').val();
    ...
    $(year).val() //Which  will result in something like $(2015).val()
```

Since the `year` is not a DOM element, you can't use `val()` on it.
You should compare the variable directly like this:

```
if(year < 2018)
```

You don't need the `'` around `2018` as it is a string

Comment: I think he passing some id or class, element to find value of which is passed in year var

Comment: He is setting the value directly to year in the first line.

Comment: no i meaning something like this `<input id='year' value='2ndinput'>
<input id='2ndinput' value='2015'>`

Comment: I agree that's a possibility, but considering the code he shared i went for this guess :)

Comment: OP needs to be more detailed and responsive

Answer (score 0):

```
if($(year).val() < '2018'){
      $('#ageres').val(results)    
     }
```

To me this is like checking `'2018'` string not number remove those `'` this will work fine.So change to this

```
if($(year).val() < 2018){
      $('#ageres').val(results)    
     }
```

What are you finding using `year` finding class,id or element using `$(year).val()`

1. if class `$('.'+year).val()`
2. if id `$('#'+year).val()`
3. if element `$(year).val()` is good to go guess

Comment: Why removing the quotes? JavaScript will still compare them if they are strings.

Comment: because he wont to check year is less than 2018 not compare to 2018 string

Comment: I thought that too, comparing a number and a string. But it turns out javascript calls `valueOf()` before doing relational operators, so it doesn't actually matter if you compare a primitive number to a string of numbers. Or compare a string of number to a string of numbers for that matter. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Relational_operators